# Application settings... should I choose 'roaming' or not?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating some application settings in a VB.NET (2010) project, with a "user" scope. What I'm trying to figure out is... should I set the "roaming" property for these applications settings to true or false?

After doing a bit of online research on the subject, I still don't understand why I would choose one option over another. So could anyone please shed some light on this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx , this also applies for this scenario (normally).

Comment: Funny you should post a link to that article, as that's one of the articles I read right before I posted my question here... which is why I'm still a bit confused, lol (seems to happen a lot whenever I visit Microsoft.com). But from what I've gathered so far... if my program is only meant to be installed on a single computer (for each user), then I don't need to use roaming. But if the program were to be installed on multiple computers (for each user), then I would want to use roaming so that the app settings would sync across all of that user's computers? Is that the gist of it?

Comment: They won't magically be shared, only if the settings are stored on a server (if the user has a roaming profile). But yeah, if you want your settings to be shared on multiple devices (for that specific user), you should create roaming settings.

Comment: This will be a desktop app... so no server involved. So I guess that makes my decision pretty easy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Forget the server part, I think you don't fully understand that part. The thing is, for example in a corporate environment, people can login on any computer they want; as they have **roaming** profiles. And thus, all their (roaming) settings will be also available on **any** computer they log on.

Comment: So you mean like an intranet server, as opposed to an internet server? Either way... I don't think I will have to worry about either of those scenarios with my target market (which would be individuals using the program on their home PC or laptop). So that said... I should probably set roaming to "false"?

Comment: Just forget about the server, that is really not important nor very relevant. Just focus about the part I explained in my previous comment. You'll have to decide for yourself... if you think (or are sure) that the "roaming" scenario is very unlikely to happen, then you could _not care_ about it too much.

Answer (score 1):

The way I think of it is this: if the settings are 1) suitable for roaming (not big) and 2) could be useful for a user who does have a roaming profile, then they should be stored for roaming. It's irrelevant how likely it is that a user of your program will have a roaming profile.  There's no down side to storing for roaming if your program never gets used by a user with a roaming profile. The only difference for a user without a roaming profile is which directory the settings are stored in.  But, if you don't store for roaming and then one day a user with a roaming profile uses your system, then they will benefit from your wise choice.